# How can I draw multiple images into a CALayer without creating additional Layers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, calayer

I am creating an Application that contains multiple Images all stacked together. The Application moves those Images frequently, so I am trying to pack them into one big container. Moving this container (of course) causes the Application to lag.

I have tried packing mutiple `UIImageView`s into one `UIView` (not a good idea) and packing multiple `CALayer`s with an Image on each one into one big `CALayer` (still not really helpfull).

So what I am looking for is an option to stick multiple Images (like a puzzle) into one `CALayer`. I don´t need to reposition those images, since I am just moving the main `Layer`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, one easy way would be to draw them yourself:
have your own custom subclass of CALayer and implement drawContext

set needsDisplayOnBoundsChange so you tell CA that you need to draw stuff yourself

Comment: I used some way that is well not too efficient. Could you give me a sample how you think the best way would be?